# Как отсортировать словарь по значению вложенного словаря без указания ключа?

Tags: python, сортировка, dict

Есть словарь:

```
{'a': {'139': '88943'},
 'b': {'138': '9677'},
 'c': {'135': '85039'}}
```

Необходимо отсортировать его по второму значению от меньшего к большему. Понимаю, что результат лежит через цикл for, но не могу его никак сформулировать.
Важно! Все ключи и значения формируются из переменных. Поэтому задействовать какую либо привязку к ключам нельзя.
Необходимо получить результат в виде:

```
{'b': {'138': '9677'},
     'c': {'135': '85039'},
     'a': {'139': '88943'}}
```

Подскажите, как это сделать или хотя бы, с чего начать.

Полный код функции.

```
def logic_to_buy():
    ddct_specific.update(ddct_sb)
    ddct_specific.update(ddct_tn)
    # Оставляет в словаре только те значения, которые больше 1000.
    my_data = ddct_specific
    new_data = {}
    for key, value in my_data.items():
        if int(list(value.values())[0]) > 1000:
            new_data.update({key: value})
```

Comment: Структура словаря всегда такая?

Comment: Да, структура неизменна. Однако, все ключи и значения являются переменными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополлнение к ответу @Danis

Словари в Python до 3.7 не гарантируют свою последовательность, то есть неважно как вы добавили ключи они при кадом запросе обекта могут быть расположенны случайным образом.

Если для вас критична сортировка лучше использовать отдельный list с ключами в который записать вашу сортировку то есть:

```
{'a': {'139': '88943'},
 'b': {'138': '9677'},
 'c': {'135': '85039'}}
```

и к нему еще:

```
sort_list = ['b', 'c', 'a']
```

---

Реализация:

```
data = {
    'a': {'139': '88943'},
    'b': {'138': '9677'},
    'c': {'135': '85039'}
}

list_by_dict = list(data.items())
list_by_dict.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1][list(x[1].keys())[0]]))

sort_dict_key = [i[0] for i in list_by_dict]
# > ['b', 'c', 'a']
```

и для итерации мы уже используем `sort_dict_key`, а не нас основной словарь.

---

Также в CPython 3.7 как фичу реализовали сохранения структуры словарей, то есть они гарантированно сохраняют свою последовательность.

---

Дока:

> Changed in version 3.7: As a dict subclass, Counter Inherited the  capability to remember insertion order. Math operations on Counter objects  also preserve order. Results are ordered according to when an element is first encountered in the left operand and then by the order encountered in

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
dict_ = {
    'b': {'138': '9677'},
     'c': {'135': '85039'},
     'a': {'139': '88943'}
}

list_ = list(dict_.items())
list_.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[1][list(x[1].keys())[0]]))
dict_ = dict(list_)
```

- `list(dict_.items())` создаём список вида `[(key1, value1), (key2, value2)]`
- `list(x[1].keys())[0]` получаем все ключи и превращаем в список чтобы можно было брать элементы по индексу, и берём первый ключ
- `int(x[1]` берём строку и превращаем в число

---

вот немного изменённая версия:

```
def f(x):
    x = x[1]
    x = list(x.values())[0]
    print(x)
    return int(x)
    
dict_ = {
     'a': {'139': '88943'},
     'b': {'138': '9677'},
      'c': {'135': '85039'}
}

list_ = list(dict_.items())
list_.sort(key = f)
dict_ = dict(list_)

for key, value in dict_.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Отсортировал по первому ключу. 
{'a: {'138': '9677'},
     'b': {'135': '85039'},
     'c': {'139': '88943'}}

Comment: Да, не работает. Попробовал отсортировать словарь my_data, который не подвергался изменениям. Тоже самое. Сортирует по по основному ключу.

Comment: @Antony  https://stackoverflow.com/q/613183/14227417

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Уже жалею, что связался с этим. Нужно было со списками работать двумя. Было бы проще.

Comment: сортировать словарь бессмысленно т.к. не имеет где находится элемент

Comment: @Antony на какой версии Python вы проверяете? стуктура словарь до 3.7 не гарантирует сортировку ключей.

Comment: Python 3.8.6 стоит

Comment: @Antony данный код тогда должен работать, вот пример: https://repl.it/@skar404/LateAttractivePixel